# What is a "chore commit"?

Tags: gitlab, git

I've seen the term "chore commit" used in multiple places, what is a chore commit?

And it's in [the commit message here](https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer/commit/5b6c43fa6bca97029f3bb23c365a9ac1b3f590e5).

> chore(gitattributes): ensured consistent line endings across OSs

What does this mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A "chore commit" is typically an automatically generated commit made by CI that either lands in a production branch, or in code on a merge-release. A chore can do things like automatically generate
and update a ChangeLog, or bump a version based on the content of other commits in the merge request.

You can see it [described here in semantic-release's commit analyzer](https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer),

> Commits with type 'chore' will not be associated with a release type.

That means a commit with a header of `chore:` will not trigger a release of any type. Which in the case of `semantic-release` is useful because the system itself generates the commit.

Chore commits pushed by themselves should not trigger CI. This typically happens in one of two ways,

- Using something like the [`-o ci.skip` push option on GitLab.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html). That is to say, to tell the CI executor not to run on that commit.
- Using a convention in the the commit message like `chore:` which the CI is contextually aware of and short circuits (skips the run).

### History

This comes from [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/#summary),

> types other than fix: and feat: are allowed, for example @commitlint/config-conventional (based on the Angular convention) recommends build:, **chore**:, ci:, docs:, style:, refactor:, perf:, test:, and others.

But as an aside, the reference [Angular convention did not adopt this term, or the chore commit type](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md), though [Karma.js did](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/git-commit-msg.html),

> chore (updating grunt tasks etc; no production code change)

Answer (score -1):

Commit types come from [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/). The idea is to annotate changes with metadata that describes the type of commit, such as fixing bugs or introducing new features. These commit types can also be tied to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) version numbers and allow for automatically calculating an appropriate version number.

Although the Conventional Commits specification only defines `fix`, `feat`, and methods for specifying breaking changes in the body of the commit message, other types are derived from other projects. For example, the Angular commit message guidelines add `build`, `ci`, `docs`, `perf`, `refactor`, `style`, and `test`. The [commitlint tool](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint) specifies `chore` as an option.

Since the definition of `chore` is not part of the Conventional Commits specification but takes advantage of its allowances for the specification of other types, it would be up to a project to specify exactly what a `chore` commit is and when it is used.